# What does %>% do in this `ggplot` command?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to understand a ggplot example in a [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/minimaxir/nyc-taxi-notebook) that Max Woolf made available. Here is the command:

```
plot <- ggplot(df %>% filter(num_pickups > 10), aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
            geom_point(color="white", size=0.06) +
            scale_x_continuous(limits=c(min_long, max_long)) +
            scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min_lat, max_lat)) +
            theme_map_dark()

png("nyc-taxi-3.png", w=600, h=600, res=300)
plot
dev.off()
```

My questions:

1. What does `%>%` do?
2. Internally, I gather that `ggplot()`, `geom_point()`, `scale_x_continuous()`, etc. are all part of the `ggplot` package, right? How does the `plot` variable do the right thing when they are all added together?
3. Is there only one plotting context? The `png()` function call generates a PNG file, but how does the system know which `ggplot()` invocation to use?
4. What does running `plot` by itself do? How does it do that?
5. Where is `dev` located? Are there other `dev` commands beyond `dev.off()` ?
6. When I run this within jupyter, the result is a PDF point with 4 million points, which causes this command line error message:

   `[I 23:26:00.318 NotebookApp] Malformed HTTP message from 127.0.0.1: Content-Length too long`

Can I sample 1% of the points to avoid this problem? How would I do that?

Comment: the `%>%` is a pipe operator that is actually part of the `dplyr` library (along with the `filter` function) not from the `ggplot2` library. To sample 1%, there is a [`sample_frac` function](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/dplyr/man/sample.html) in the `dplyr` library. It would be something like `(df %>% sample_frac(0.01))`

Comment: Ideally each post should ask just one question at a time because they can have at most one accepted answer.

Comment: Q4: `apropos("^dev\\.")`

Comment: @MrFlick, true, but all of these seem connected.

Comment: Do you actually get a plot completed on the png file when you run it in R? I would have expected it to be empty from that code.

Comment: Yes, I get a plot. Why would you expect it to be empty?

Comment: Wow, I've never gotten -6 on a question before. That's harsh.

Answer (score 3):

1. `%>%` is a pipe operator reexported from the `magrittr` package.  Start by reading the vignette.

   [Introducing magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)
2. Adding things to a ggplot changes the object that gets created.  The print method of ggplot draws an appropriate plot depending upon the contents of the variable.  Take a look at `str(plot)`.
3. Plots are drawn on devices: either a file or an R figure window. `png` opens a PNG file device.
4. I assume you mean your ggplot object, not the function of the same name.  Typing `plot` at the command line calls `print.ggplot(plot)`, which draws the plot in the current device, an R figure window by default.
5. As Ben Bolker said, try `apropos("dev")`.  Also try `?dev.off`, `find("dev.off")`, and `getAnywhere("dev.off")`.
6. Try the `sample` function.